# How to persistently maintain cloned mac address on Network Manager?

Tags: gnome, network-manager, scripts, find

I'm on Gnome 3, and it seems like I'm able to add cloned mac address to my network interfaces from the GUI wizard of Network Manager.

The catch is, every time I reboot my computer the cloned mac address of specific devices that I had set earlier are no longer there. Therefore I have to resort to re-entering those details manually again and again, every time I reboot my computer.

- Is there any 'simple' automated script or command-line solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I find Gnome's NetworkManager frontend quite buggy if using some special configurations. You can always use `nmcli` (NetworkManager cli) to configure network profiles:

First, copy the network profile `UUID` you want to modify. You can list all UUIDs with (ignore `$` symbol):

```
$ nmcli c
```

Next, use `nmcli` to configure the desired profile:

```
$ nmcli connection edit UUID_OF_THE_NETWORK_PROFILE
nmcli> set 802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address MAC_ADDRESS
```

Changing `UUID` and `MAC_ADDRESS` with the ones you want to use. Finally, save the profile with:

```
nmcli> save persistent
nmcli> quit
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this from Gnome desktop using the network manager UI.

Go to 'Network' settings. Edit a Wi-Fi (or other connection), go to 'Identity', enter the new mac address in the 'Cloned Address' field then click 'Apply'. Turn the wifi on and off.

METHOD 1 for verifying:

If you execute `ifconfig` in the command line, you should see a line under the connection that says something like: `ether A4:69:1b:1B:2B:A1`

METHOD 2 for verifying:

`ip link show interface`

Where interface is like `eth0`, `wlp2s0`, etc (you can run `nmcli c` to see all the interfaces, the name you're looking for would be under `DEVICE` column).

You should see a line that says something like `link/ether A4:69:1b:1B:2B:A1`